# Need only accept Xml files and only show .xml file extension in select window

Tags: html, xml, fileinputstream

I need only accept xml files from file input. I already add accept='text/xml' but in my file window file type show as custom files. How to change custom files into xml files
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the way that's simply add

```
<input accept=".xml" type="file"/>
```